# If you fork() and exec() from the child process, and wait in the parent, how does the parent get a return code from the child?

Tags: unix, process, fork, exec, wait

I'm learning about `fork()`, `exec()`, etc. and I ran into something in a textbook that I don't fully understand.

In the example, a process calls `fork()`.

In the child process, we call `exec()`.

Later, in the parent, we call `wait()`.

It is my understanding that a successful `exec()` call never returns. If we called `exec()` in the child, how can we wait for the child to return in the parent, if the child will never have control returned to it from the `exec()`?

My only guess here is that what happens is the parent, thinking it's waiting on the child, is actually waiting on the new process created with exec? I.e. normally I'd `fork()` and wait for the child. If I `fork()` and exec the UNIX program `date` then wait for the child in the parent, am I actually now waiting for `date` to exit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish the *process* from the *program*. Calling `exec` runs a different program in the same process. The `exec` function doesn't return (except to signal an error) because it terminates the program that calls in. However, the process is reused to run a different program. In a way, from the perspective of the process running `exec`, the `exec` function returns as the entry point of the new program.

From the point of view of the parent, there's a child process. That's all the parent knows. The parent doesn't know that the child called `exec`, unless it watches it and finds out by indirect means such as running `ps`. The parent is just waiting for the child process to exit, no matter what program the child process happens to be running.